# How to work with multiple files of Typescript in Visual studio code?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am learning typescript and try to get also the debugging working as well.

I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.14.1
Typescript version 2.4.1
NodeJs version 8.1.4

Here is the repository with the code https://github.com/sherry-ummen/tryingouttypescriptdebugging

**tasks.json**

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-w", "-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "isBackground": true,
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
}
```

**launch.json**

```
    {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "Launch",
                "type": "node",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}/Test.ts",
                "stopOnEntry": false,
                "args": [],
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "preLaunchTask": null,            
                "runtimeExecutable": null,
                "runtimeArgs": [
                    "--nolazy"
                ],
                "env": {
                    "NODE_ENV": "development"
                },
                "console": "integratedTerminal",
                "sourceMaps": true,
                "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/out/*.js"]
            },
            {
                "name": "Attach",
                "type": "node",
                "request": "attach",
                "port": 5858
            }
        ]
    }
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "target": "es6", 
            "outDir": "out/",
            "sourceMap": true
        },
        "files": [
            "IShape.ts",
            "Circle.ts",
            "Triangle.ts",
            "Test.ts"
        ]    
    }
```

So the compilation is working fine atleast does not give error. But when I press F5 on visual studio code to run it then I get the following error

[image: 1]

Could someone please guide me on how to get this working with visual studio code ?

Comment: Why are you expecting the Triangle, Circle and IShape to be inside your Drawing namespace? Also `<reference />`s only work for types, not for actual values. For that you'll need to import or require them.

Comment: OK I am still learning and experimenting with typescript so my knowledge is very limited, but what I thought that I defined IShape and others inside Drawing namespace so it should be accessible to me in my Test.ts .

Comment: You didn't. Triangle, Circle etc are in their own files so they are not defined in the namespace that you are currently working in. You need to import them first and then use them by their proper names, i.e. `Triangle`, `Circle`, etc

Comment: About your suggestion related to reference , could you elaborate more what do you mean?

Comment: to use those objects inside your files you need to `import Triangle from './Triangle'`, not `<reference />` them.

Comment: ohh ok I have to investigate that how to do it.

Comment: The official handbook provides guidance on [exporting and importing modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Comment: interesting, I will read that link then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out with the help of the comments I got and also tweaking my tsconfig.json file.

I wrote a blog post about it on how to get started with the debugging if someone bumps up with the same issue then they can refer this post https://sherryummen.in/2017/07/14/debugging-multiple-typescript-files-using-vscode/